# Limpar objectos com subobjetos vazios

Tags: javascript

Olá. Hoje surgiu-me uma dúvida. Como posso, de uma forma eficiente, criar uma função que permita-me limpar um objeto específico? Por exemplo:

```
const obj = {
   chave1: 'conteudo',
   chave2: {},
   chave3: '',
   chave4: {
    chave1: 'conteudo1',
    chave2: {}
    chave3: {
       chave1: [],
       chave2: {},
       chave3 'conteudo2'
    }
   }
}
```

Como output teria de sair o seguinte:

```
{
  chave1: 'conteudo',
  chave4: {
   chave1: 'conteudo1',
   chave3: {
    chave3: 'conteudo2',
   }
  }
}
```

Como posso solucionar o problema sem que comprometa a performance?

Comment: isso depende da versão que estas a usar.. es2015 ? es2016 ? nativo ?

Comment: "Como posso solucionar o problema sem que comprometa a performance?" Não quero saber de verões mas sim de performance. Qual a melhor forma de iterar objetos? Independentemente das versões.

Comment: "Sem que comprometa a performance" – isso vai depender do objeto. É preciso iterar sobre o objeto todo para remover os valores vazios, não tem outro jeito. Isso custa tempo de processamento. Se o objeto for pequeno, não deve ter muito impacto na performance. Se for grande, pode ter mais impacto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só varrer as propriedades do objeto e usar `delete` naquelas que estão vazias, fazendo isso de forma recursiva. Veja abaixo a função `limpar` que faz isso:

```js
const obj = {
    chave1: 'conteudo',
    chave2: {},
    chave3: '',
    chave4: {
        chave1: 'conteudo1',
        chave2: {},
        chave3: {
            chave1: [],
            chave2: {},
            chave3: 'conteudo2'
        }
    }
};

function limpar(obj) {
    var vazio = true;
    for (var e in obj) {
        var k = obj[e];
        if (!k || ((k instanceof Object || k instanceof Array) && limpar(k))) {
            delete obj[e];
        } else {
            vazio = false;
        }
    }
    return vazio;
}

limpar(obj);
console.log(obj);
```